# How Jmx bean of Hikari cp can be used in spring boot when boot autoconfigure pooling

Tags: spring-boot, jmx, hikaricp

How `Jmx bean` of `Hikari cp` can be used in `spring boot` when boot `autoconfigure pooling`?

i tried following this instruction in below link.

https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/MBean-(JMX)-Monitoring-and-Management.

Hre is my mbean class

```
import javax.management.JMX;
import javax.management.MBeanServer;
import javax.management.ObjectName;
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;


    @ManagedResource(
            objectName="PD:category=MBeans,name=testBean",
            description="Managed Bean")
    @Component("testMbean")
    public class HikariJmx {

        private String message = "Simple Message";

        private int size=0;
        public HikariJmx(){
            System.out.println("......TestMbean........");
        }

        @ManagedOperation
        public void resetMessageViaMBean(){
            this.message = "Message RESET";
        }

    @ManagedAttribute
    public int getSize() throws Exception{
            try {
                MBeanServer mBeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
                ObjectName poolName = new ObjectName("com.zaxxer.hikari:type=Pool (HikariPool-1)");
                HikariPoolMXBean poolProxy = JMX.newMXBeanProxy(mBeanServer, poolName, HikariPoolMXBean.class);
                return poolProxy.getIdleConnections();
            }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

            return 0;
        }
    }
```

> Iam able to see the bean in visual vm. But when i take the attribute SIZE i am getting `instanceNotFound` exception in below line.

```
ObjectName poolName = new ObjectName("com.zaxxer.hikari:type=Pool (HikariPool-1)");
```

I am not creating datasource manually, just gave the properties in the `application.properties` and boot do the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem.

You can get the HikariPoolMXBean from the HikariDataSource itself.

In order to do that, I injected the HikariDataSource to the class I needed the HikariPoolMXBean, and called this method :

```
HikariPoolMXBean poolProxy = hikariDataSource.getHikariPoolMXBean();
```